# .htaccess rewrite to subfolders for subdomains and the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

There's tons of resources online about using .htaccess to rewrite your subdomains and if need be, also rewrite your main domain to a subfolder. I have found plenty answers and most of them are exactly the same. I have been tediously testing these methods and I have the same problem in all cases.

Consider the wanted result:
**maindomain.com** : rewrite to /public_html/mainsite/
**sub.maindomain.com** : rewrite to /public_html/sub/

The fastest/cleanest way i have considered is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [L]

# Rewrite the sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

This works well except for 1 annoying issue; The line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite
```

Basically prevents a rewrite loop, but if you browse to maindomain.com/mainsite/ it rewrites to /public_html/mainsite/ instead of /public_html/mainsite/mainsite/ hoping to raise a 404 not found. If i remove that line, i get a 500 server error as it goes into a loop :S

The issue is, that any one of these domains needs freedom of creating folders etc. and would like to ensure that there is absolute freedom in the sub-sub folders people create :S

Please could someone help here?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [L]

# Rewrite the sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

You need to make it so that it does not match any file within the /mainsite directory not just the root (/mainsite). I would think you would need to do the same to the sub domain also.

Comment: !^/mainsite/.*i is the same as !^/mainsite/ (greedy regexp). You also need to escape dots in "sub.maindomain.com" otherwise subbmaindomain.com would match, or even subbmaindomainccom.org or even subbmaindomainccom.maindomain.com ;-) Anyway, I'm still thinking about the most elegant solution.

Comment: That is true, you do need to escape the dots. Did not know about greedy regexp, thought you needed the .*

Answer (score 0):

actually try this if you are still looking for an answer

```
RewriteEngine On 
# Rewrite the main domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub.maindomain.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite/.* 
RewriteRule ^/mainsite/(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [L] 

# Rewrite the sub domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.maindomain.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/.* 
RewriteRule ^/sub/(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]`
```